# loop over nested lists 'ol' elements

Tags: jquery, json, list, serialization, nested-lists

I am trying to serialize my hierarhical list to json object like that;

```
[
  {title: title1,id: 1,children: [
              {title: title1_1,id: 1_1,children: [
                   {title: title1_1_1,id: 1_1_1,children: []},
                   {title: title1_1_2,id: 1_1_2,children: []}
              ]}
   ]},
   {title: title2,id: 2,children: [
        {title: title2_1,id: 2_2,children: []}
   ]}
 ]
```

My list structure goes like this:

```
<ol class="sortable">
    <li><label>title1</label>
        <ol>
            <li><label>title1_1</label>
                <ol>
                    <li><label>title1_1_1</label>
                        <ol></ol>
                    </li>
                    <li><label>title1_1_2</label>
                        <ol></ol>
                    </li>
                </ol>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    <li><label>title2</label>
        <ol>
            <li><label>title2_1</label>
                <ol></ol>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </li>
</ol>
```

I've wrote my serialization function:

```
function toJson(object, jsonObject) {
    return jsonObject 
           + "{\"title\":\"" 
           + object.children('label').text() 
           + "\", \"children\":\"" 
           + listToJson(object.children("ol").children("li"),jsonObject) 
           + "\"}";
}

function listToJson(list,jsonObject) {
    jsonObject = jsonObject + "[";
    list.each(function(idx, li) {
        jsonObject = toJson($(li).children('ol'),jsonObject);
    });
    jsonObject = jsonObject + "]";
    return jsonObject;
}
```

and excecution of function:

```
  var jsonObject = "";
  jsonObject = listToJson($("ol.sortable > li"),jsonObject);
```

But I cant make it work. I think it is cause when I call `.children(ol)` it goes throu whole structure instead stopping on first level.

Can any one help me?

Comment: Why are some children multi-dimensional arrays and some single-dimensional arrays in your JSON example?

Comment: It was copy/paste mistake of mine. I've corrected it. Can You look on it now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you've resorted to manually creating JSON, I don't recommend ever doing that.  Here is something much simplified:

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    function toObject(element)
    {
        var result = [];
        // make sure we're using jquery elements
        var $element = $(element);
        var $children = $element.children('li');
        $children.each(function()
        {
            var $this = $(this);
            var item = {};
            item.title = '';

            var $label = $this.find('label').first();
            if ($label.length == 1)
            {
                item.title = $label.text();
            }

            // should only be one OL
            var $grandchild = $this.children('ol').first();

            item.children = toObject($grandchild);

            result.push(item);
        });

        return result;
    }

    var $target = $('ol.sortable');
    var o = toObject($target);
    var json = JSON.stringify(o);

    $('pre').text(json);
});
```

Result (much better JSON anyway):

> [{"title":"Faza przygotowawcza","children":[{"title":"Uzyskaj dane kontaktowe klienta","children":[{"title":"Wizytówka klienta","children":[]},{"title":"Ankieta- Dane klienta","children":[]}]}]},{"title":"Faza realizacji","children":[{"title":"Wprowadź klienta do systemu","children":[]}]}]

I didn't add the ID, but if you really need it let me know it's not hard to add to this code.

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/g6x5ed0m/)

Comment: It look promising. I will check it in 10 hours (as soon as I arrive home). By the way, I will need to add some extras parameters like: id,type,active,icon, etc. F.e: `<li><label e_id='1' e_active='true' e_type='file' e_icon='fa-file'></label></li>`

Comment: What is the most important I will want to edit structure, labels, custom attributes values. So it have to refresh whole list before serialize. Here is my fork: http://jsfiddle.net/g6x5ed0m/13/

Comment: If you have ownership over the name of the attributes, I'd highly recommend [prefixing your custom attributes with `data-`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) (eg. `data-type="file" data-icon="fa-file"`).  jQuery even has a custom method [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) that was created for the specific purpose of reading and converting these elements into native types (unlike attr()).